# Как осуществить переход из одного switch-case в другой и вернуться обратно?

Tags: java, android

Нужна помощь с логикой реализации функционала, рабочих идей у меня к сожалению нет, все что пробовал реализовать не получается.

На экране есть несколько текстовых полей и иконок.
Так же есть 2 кнопки, на которые выводятся определенные значения. В зависимости от того, какую кнопку нажал пользователь меняется:

- отображаемая информация в текстовых полях (количество текстовых полей может уменьшаться или увеличиваться, обычно в пределах +/-1);
- иконки (контент, а так же их количество);
- выводимая информация на кнопки.

Значения для кнопок берут из БД по их ID. В `setNEXT_ACTION_one/two` передается ID, и через `setText` устанавливается значение. Выбор и ветвление происходит по средством `switch-case`:

```
  public void switchAction_one(){
        switch (getNEXT_ACTION_one()){
            case 1: setStages_move(2); setNEXT_ACTION_one(3); setNEXT_ACTION_two(4);
                break;
            case 3: setStages_move(4); setNEXT_ACTION_one(5); setNEXT_ACTION_two(4);
                break;
            case 5: setStages_move(6); setNEXT_ACTION_one(7); setNEXT_ACTION_two(8);
                break;
            case 7: setStages_move(8); setNEXT_ACTION_one(9); setNEXT_ACTION_two(10);
                break;
            case 9: setStages_move(9); setNEXT_ACTION_one(0); setNEXT_ACTION_two(0); 
                break;
        }
    }
```

Мне нужно реализовать следующую логику:
Когда попадается определенное значение, например `case 10,` то ветвление переходит в совершенно другую ветку `switch-case`, логично, что это будет реализовано в другом методе. Там у пользователя будет счетчик нажатий на кнопки. Какие-то действия уменьшают счетчик, другие действия увеличивают счетчик. При достижении опреднленного значения, процесс должен вернуться к исходному дереву `switch-case`, к следующему значению (переход был на "10", значит вернуться должен к "11".

Буду признателен за любые конструктивные предложения.

Comment: посмотрете ка роботают  метки  в  java

Comment: Обратно с другой стороны?